# Convert math formula to javascript

Tags: javascript, math, translate

I need help converting a loan balance formula into JavaScript I have added the formula image of the

[image]

This is how I currently have it, but I keep getting the wrong answer.

```
 var loanBalance = a * Math.pow((1 + r), n) - p * ((Math.pow((1 + r), n) - 1) / r);
```

My calculator has four functions but only this one is giging me the wrong answer, as you can seen I am new to all this, thanks in advance.

Here is the function that I am having trouble with:

```
      function doBalance() {
        var principal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("borrowedBox").value);
        var annualRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rateBox").value);
        var years = parseFloat(document.getElementById("yearsBox").value);
        var periodsPerYear = parseFloat(document.getElementById("paymentBox").value);
        var numberOfPaymentsPaidToDate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("toDatePymtsBox").value);
        var result = 0;
        result = computeBalance(principal, annualRate, years, periodsPerYear, numberOfPaymentsPaidToDate);
        document.getElementById("outputDiv2").innerHTML = "$" + result;
    }

    function computeBalance(principal, annualRate, years, periodsPerYear, numberOfPaymentsPaidToDate) {
        var a = principal;
        var r = annualRate/periodsPerYear;
        var p = periodsPerYear*years;
        var n = numberOfPaymentsPaidToDate;
        var loanBalance = (a * (Math.pow((1 + r), n))) -( (p * (Math.pow((1 + r), n) - 1)) / r);
        return loanBalance.toFixed(2);
    }
```

The answer should be 54306.40
These are the values I am using:
[Loan Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcgA5.jpg)

Comment: at a glance it looks like you've created the function correctly ... is it out by a lot?

Comment: can you provide some sample input output ?? like what is providing and what is expecting answer

Comment: Where did you get that formula? Perhaps it's wrong or you are giving the wrong input

Comment: I have added the function that is giving me trouble, the answer should be 54306.40 and it keeps giving me other things every time I change the brackets around.

Comment: @JaromandaX I am starting to think that it might be the right answer, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I typed the equation given into a calculator with the values provided and got back the value generated by your code. Therein your code generates the "correct" number. It seems as though your equation is wrong or `a`, `r`, `p`, and `n` formulas are not what the equation given expects.

Comment: @TMKelleher thanks for clearing that up, I have tested it with other online calculators and it appears that my code is right as you have stated. I was thinking that my answer was wrong because I was following an example that displayed a different answer than what my code is giving. It's the last time I believe book examples, I lost too much time and it made it difficult for me to learn this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Split the formula,

```
function loanBalancer(r,n,p,a){
  var powerfn = Math.pow((1+r), n);
  var firstprt = a * powerfn;
  var num = p(powerfn - 1);
  var den = r;
  return firstprt - (num/den) 
}
```

Comment: This gives the same answer as the original question. How do you believe it has helped?

Answer (score 2):

I think your brackets are just slightly off:

```
var loanBalance = a * Math.pow((1 + r), n) - (p * ((Math.pow((1 + r), n) - 1)) / r);
```

Comment: This gives the same answer as the original question. How do you believe it has helped?

Comment: The brackets you've added make no difference at all. Multiplication and division have preference over addition and subtraction, so the part that you've wrapped in parenthesis will be evaluated before being subtracted even if the brackets aren't present.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have resolved the fact that the code you have written is behaving correctly and producing the correct result, I would give a small recommendation. Apply some algebra to reduce the expression to get:

```
b = (((1+r)^n)(ra-p) + p)/r
```

In code...

```
b = (Math.pow(1+r, n)(r*a - p) + p)/r;
```

That would reduce the amount of computation for your calculation:)

Answer (score -2):

First of all the brackets need to be placed properly

```
var loanBalance = (a * (Math.pow((1 + r), n))) -( (p * (Math.pow((1 + r), n) - 1)) / r);
```

Comment: This gives the same answer as the original question. How do you believe it has helped?

Comment: The extra brackets make no difference to the order of evaluation of the values. Even the OP has more brackets than necessary.

Comment: ok, if you think its not working  provide me the correct output with some input values of variable.